# What is the approach to subscribe events from Azure Storage account which has access to only a limited virtual networks?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-eventgrid

I am getting the following error when trying to create an Azure Event Subscription from Azure Storage to Azure Function.

```
The attempt to configure storage notifications for the provided storage account <storage-name> failed.
Please ensure that your storage account meets the requirements described at https://aka.ms/storageevents.
The error is Failed to retrieve credentials for request=RequestUri=https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<sub-id>/resourceGroups/<rg>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAcco...
```

I suspect the issue is related to Azure Event Subscription unable to connect to the Storage Account due to the network restrictions. Am I missing some necessary steps?

Comment: Is your storage account version 1 or 2?

Answer (score -1):

This error is not due to the virtual network. In fact, the errors displayed already tell you the direction of the problem. View this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview

Only storage accounts of kind StorageV2 (general purpose v2) and BlobStorage support event integration. Storage (genral purpose v1) does not support integration with Event Grid.

Create a v2 Storage account and the problem should disappear.

Comment: The storage account is a v2 storage account.